# Image Upsampling

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, resampling

I don't know if this specifically belongs on Stack Overflow; but I will post it here with hopes that it will be moved to the right section (if this is indeed the wrong section).

I have Photoshop, and was wondering if there was a way to re-size / re-sample a picture that I have that I took with a cell phone. Now I know what you're thinking, and I know that this is not the most practical thing to do; as the resolution of the camera is exceedingly low. I am mainly looking to try and make the image bigger while keeping the image as clear / unpixelated as possible.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you directly from the beginning, I am not the absolute Photoshop god, but I have worked with it.

For simple resizing you have in the image menu a size option. There you can simply re-size your picture. But for sure, depending on the quality of the source picture you will have quality loss.

For re-sampling, I have never seen a function for that in Photoshop and I don't think there is one somewhere hidden. The software is not made for that. Manipulating graphics and re-sampling are two very different tasks.

Hope that helps at least a little bit.